# An error appears when calling a function that prints a C++ list

Tags: c++, list, function, stack, call

I designed the algorithm as follows to solve the problem, but an error occurs when calling printList(ans).
In the test case, when checking '-' among the given strings, I guess that there was an error in the erase process.
Does anyone have any thoughts on the cause of this error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <list>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;


void printList(list<char> a) {
    list<char>::iterator it;
    for (it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it ;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void keyLogger(string a){

    stack<char>key; 
    list<char>ans; 
    auto itor = ans.begin();
    //list<char>::iterator itor = ans.begin(); 

    for (char x : a) {
        switch (x) {
        case '<':
            key.push(x);
            break;
        case '>':
            key.push(x);
            break;
        case '-':
            if (itor == ans.begin()) break;
            else {
                ans.erase(itor);
                itor--;
            }
            break;
        default:
            while (!key.empty()) {
                switch (key.top()) {
                    case '<':
                        if (itor == ans.begin()) break;
                        else itor--;
                        break;
                    case '>':
                        if (itor == ans.end()) break;
                        else itor++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        cout << "Wrong Character is in Stack." << endl;
                }
                        key.pop();
            } // get out of the while, when the stack is empty

            ans.insert(itor, x); // insert 'x' into the stack's next to itor.
        }
    }
    printList(ans); // ERROR
}


int main() {
    int test; cin >> test;
    for (int i = 0; i < test; i++) {
        string a;
        cin >> a;
        keyLogger(a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And is the iterator automatically incremented when erase or insert? After executing insert below, I did not increase itor, but insert is proceeding normally. I'm also curious about the cause of this.

Comment: What does "an error occurs" mean? What kind of an error? A compilation error? A runtime error? What does the error message say? If it's a compilation error what is the line on which the compilation error is reported? If it's a runtime error, what happens when you run your program, one line at a time, in your debugger, up to the point of the error, what do you see in your debugger?

Comment: instead of doing `ans.erase(itor); itor--;`, do `itor = ans.erase(itor);`. I don't know if it's going to fix your error but it surely is better.

Comment: `erase` and `insert` invalidate iterators, but return a new, valid iterator that you can use.

Comment: Some advice learn about passing parameters by (const) reference (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/passing-arguments-by-reference/), a call to printList will now copy your whole list. And unlearn to use "using namespace std;" And a there is a better way to loop over your items in printlist as well : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for